# R limma voom function mean-variance trend

Tags: r, variance, mean

I am using the limma package in R to do some analysis on a count data matrix. I use the voom function and that normally creates a plot with the mean variance trend line in it. Now I created also a mean variance trend plot, but it doesn't look normal.

Has anyone seen something like this before?

[image]

Comment: It shouldn't look like a normal because count data is not likely to have a normal shape.  Poisson and negative binomial are common shapes and can be highly skewed.  The counts could look approximately normal if they are sums of several iid count variables.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you get a close enough distribution, without the wolverine claws.

In your case, transcripts within a particular count range possess a linear correlation with the square root of the standard deviation. It's definitely a technical problem, but your data may still be good. Check, first of all if it comes form a particular sample of your dataset (or group of samples). Then, check if the transcripts measured in that range are incorrectly measured (e.g. if you have a similar experiment, even in [GEO](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/), plot the absolute expression ranks against each other).

[image]